# Error in shift operator using numeric literals but not with numeric constant

Tags: go, constants, literals

I am getting error while doing a shift operation in go with `invalid operation: 1 << bucketCntBits (shift count type int, must be unsigned integer)` error on trying to declare a literal in go inside `main()` body
Failing literal example: https://play.golang.org/p/EqI-yag5yPp

```
func main() {
    bucketCntBits := 3 // <---- This doesn't work
    bucketCnt     := 1 << bucketCntBits
    fmt.Println("Hello, playground", bucketCnt)
}
```

When I declare the shift count as a constant, the shift operator works.
Working constant example: https://play.golang.org/p/XRLL4FR8ZEl

```
const (
    bucketCntBits = 3 // <---- This works
)

func main() {

    bucketCnt     := 1 << bucketCntBits
    fmt.Println("Hello, playground", bucketCnt)
}
```

Why does the constant work while the literal doesn't for the shift operator?

Comment: Because in Go contants *can* be **untyped**, variables can *not*. So with an untyped constant the type of the value is inferred from the operator, but using the operator on the wrong typed variable, or constant, will break. Try `const bucketCntBits int = 3` to see that this has less to do with `const` and more to do with types.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> [Go 1.13 Release Notes (September 2019)](https://golang.org/doc/go1.13)
>
> Changes to the language
>
> Per the [signed shift counts proposal](https://github.com/golang/proposal/blob/master/design/19113-signed-shift-counts.md) Go 1.13 removes the
>   restriction that a shift count must be unsigned. This change
>   eliminates the need for many artificial uint conversions, solely
>   introduced to satisfy this (now removed) restriction of the << and >>
>   operators.

---

```
invalid operation: 1 << bucketCntBits (shift count type int, must be unsigned integer)
```

This is no longer an error for Go 1.13 (September 2019) and later.

Your example,

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    bucketCntBits := 3
    bucketCnt := 1 << bucketCntBits
    fmt.Println(bucketCnt)
}
```

Output:

```
$ go version
go version devel +66ff373911 Sat Aug 24 01:11:56 2019 +0000 linux/amd64

$ go run shift.go
8
```

Answer (score 0):

Or, you can cast the type `uint8`, `uint16`, `uint32` or `uint64` for integer literal. For example,

```
func main() {
    bucketCntBits := uint32(3)
    bucketCnt     := 1 << bucketCntBits
    fmt.Println(bucketCnt)
}
```

Output:

```
8
```

Answer (score -2):

With `math/bits` package you can do soemthing like this:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math/bits"
)

func main() {
    bucketCntBits := 3
    bucketCnt     := bits.RotateLeft(1, bucketCntBits)
    fmt.Println("Hello, playground", bucketCnt)
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/fVK2xysL896